# Which package does the ""<Program>" is not responding" dialog belong to?

Tags: bug-reporting

I wish to file a bug report against the package with the `"<Program>" is not responding.` dialog belongs to:

[image: ""Apport" is not responding." example dialog]

So which package does it belong to? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

**Clarification:** I am interested in the program which is showing the dialog about the unresponsive program, not the program which is unresponsive. So unless Apport is the program which is displaying the dialog, and would be *no matter* which program is unresponsive, then Apport is not the program which I am interested in.

Comment: you can run `xprop` or `xwindow` ( `xprop` is more verbose and has better info, so i'd prefer that),  and when cursor turns into an` X` click on that dialog to find out what program it belongs to. Specifically , look for `WM_CLASS` property

Comment: @Serg: `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "zenity", "mutter-dialog"` was the output containing `WM_CLASS`. So does that mean that it belongs to `zenity` then?

Comment: Zenity is just a command-line tool to display simple GTK dialog windows... Not sure if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Nah, in that case, if it's zenity, that cannot be the issue.

Comment: @Serg: The report I want to file is about the design and workings of that dialog so is `zenity` not what I should file it under?

Comment: But it says right there that "Apport" is not responding. It's supposed to be a system that collects info from crashed processes.  I would check `/var/log/apport.log` , see if there's anything of interest there.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda so you really only care about the dialog ? Not the specific issue of why it's being shown ?

Comment: @Serg: The reason why it's being shown is a separate issue which I will report. If I crash Firefox instead I will get the same dialog, and be able to reproduce the same bug. The bug I want to know about is in the dialog, not the program I crashed.

Comment: @kos: I'm not interested in the program which is unresponsive and being reported, I am interested in which program launches that dialog. I have updated my question. How much clearer do I need to be?

Comment: AH ok, I see what you mean. Then yes, technically it's Zenity, but Zenity just displays the popup, something else is invoking it.

Comment: @kos: So to which package do I complain to about the workings and design of the popup?

Comment: No idea, but not to Zenity. And that's not specific to GNOME if you're wondering, it's the same in Unity etc. Not sure what triggers it. In this case I think it's ok to report it directly to Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu.

Comment: @kos: I don't think that that is possible because when I press the "Report a Bug" button it just redirects me to [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Indeed you didn't read the page. There are instructions on how to report the bug using the pre-installed tools. If you really want to do that online, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug?no-redirect, but that's discouraged.

Comment: @kos: I have read that page before... I know that there are instructions using the offline tool there, however you have to specify to the offline tool what package the issue needs to be reported under... And as we don't know how am I going to do that?

Comment: Under "Filing a general bug against no particular package": "First, please review potential package candidates [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage). Only after reviewing this, if are still not sure which package is affected by the bug, type ubuntu-bug in the “Run Command” screen and press Enter. This will guide you through a series of questions to gather more information about the bug and help you assign it to the appropriate package."

Comment: @kos: You should give it a go. All that does is ask you which category the package goes into, and also asks you if it is related to certain commands, and if it is not (and trust me I have looked through all the options and they all end up in filing a report to the wrong package for this) then it just says "You need to specify a package or PID.". Please just run `ubuntu-bug` for yourself and if you can find a way of finding the appropriate package for this then that's great and let me know! Until then please don't keep telling me to use `ubuntu-bug` or that silly guide that doesn't help...

Comment: That's another problem. Try https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug?no-redirect

Comment: @kos: Thanks! That worked! I'll probably post an answer then when I find out which package it is...